# How can I limit how much a program can utilise my GPU?

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, gentoo

I'm currently running a program called `BOINC` [(BOINC website)](https://boinc.berkeley.edu/)

It is able to use my `GTX 1080` ti, however, it never seems to want to abide by its own settings on my system and so it hogs my GPU while I'm using my PC and it makes KDE feel slow.

Is there a way for me to get `Linux` to force the program to not take all the resources from my `GPU`?

I don't want to limit the GPU utilization for all programs and effectively handicap my system for no reason, just for that one so other programs can still use it. If that's not possible, what could I do to help mitigate the issue?

Perhaps I can change the GPU scheduler (if that's even possible)? I'm using the proprietary drivers btw. I'm perfectly fine with compiling and configuring the kernel if required.

Comment: It might be easier to set BOINC to only run when system is idle. That frees the GPU for other tasks when you're at the computer and gives BOINC the entire GPU to play with when you're away for lunch and stuff.

Comment: @Mioriin I did try doing that, but it seems to take a while for boinc to stop using the GPU. It would usually be quicker for me to just stop boincs daemon then start it again to get boinc to let go of the GPU, so I thought forcing it to use something like 95% of my GPU will still leave enough GPU for the desktop and other basic things while  boinc is still allowed to use most of the GPU (opposed to it just not using it at all while I'm using it).

Answer (score 0):

The Red Circle is optional, but you need to check the box outlined in blue:

[image]